# is there any R function/s to find a word and then save the following words until I reach a special character in another new column?

Tags: r

For example, if my data frame is as follows-

Column_id    Column_text
123          A: Hello 
 B: Hi, How are you?
A: I am good. What about you?
B: Good, 
              thanks

How can I get the output in the following format?

Column_id     Column_text        Text_from_A                         Text_from_B
123           (all the text)      Hello I am good. What about you    Hi, how are you? good,thanks

I basically need A text and B text in two different columns which should be added to my original data frame.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Updated posted: This is how it looks with dput

structure(list(Id = 12:13, Body_text = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Chat started: Thursday, December 5, 2019, 13:15:09 
 Chat Origin sales department
 Agent John
 John: Hi, How may I help you today?
 John: Please hold on for a moment.
Customer: Hi, I have a question regarding a car model Price.
, John: Yes, may I know which model it is?
 Customer: Yes, model abc.
 John:The price of this is $$$$$.
 Customer: Thank you
 John:Have a good day.
", 
"Chat started: wednesday, December 4, 2019, 13:15:09 
 Chat Origin sales department
 Agent Mike
 Mike: Hi, How may I help you today?
Customer: Hi, I would like to know the price of ABC car model
 John:The price of this is $$$$$.
 Customer: Thank you
 Mike:Have a good day!
 Customer:Thanks, you too!
 "
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", "Body_text"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

[image: Output_format]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esQBQ.png)

I am trying to write the ouput to a csv file but not getting ... don't know where I am going wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(bindrcpp)

df2<-read.csv("filepath.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")

df2 %>%
    mutate(Body_text = sub("^.*Agent\\s\\w+", "", Body_text)) %>%
    separate_rows(Body_text, sep="\\s(?=\\w+:)") %>% 
    separate(Body_text, into = c("Text_from", "value"), sep=":\\s?") %>%
    na.omit %>% 
    group_by(Id, newgrp = str_c('Text_from_', 
        replace(Text_from, Text_from != "Customer", "Agent"))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = newgrp, values_from = value) %>%
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    result<-summarise(AgentName = first(Text_from),
              Text_from_Agent = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Agent), collapse=' '),
              Text_from_Customer = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Customer), collapse = ' '))%>%
   write.csv(result,"filepathresult.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to expand the rows by splitting at the space before an upper case letter followed by the `:`, then split the 'Column_text' into two ("Text_from", "value"), reshape into 'wide' format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
 df1 %>%
    separate_rows(Column_text, sep="\\s(?=[A-Z]:)") %>% 
    separate(Column_text, into = c("Text_from", "value"), sep=":\\s+") %>%
    mutate(Text_from = str_c("Text_from_", Text_from)) %>% 
    group_by(Column_id, Text_from) %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = Text_from, values_from = value) %>%
    select(-rn) # %>%
    # if need do a group by paste
    # group_by(Column_id) %>%
    # summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), toString)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Column_id [1]
#  Column_id Text_from_A                Text_from_B     
#      <dbl> <chr>                      <chr>           
#1       123 Hello                      Hi, How are you?
#2       123 I am good. What about you? Good, thanks
```

#### Update

Based on the updated dataset, we can slightly modify the regex and use the same logic

```
df2 %>%
    mutate(Body_text = sub("^.*Agent\\s\\w+", "", Body_text)) %>%
    separate_rows(Body_text, sep="\\s(?=\\w+:)") %>% 
    separate(Body_text, into = c("Text_from", "value"), sep=":\\s?") %>%
    na.omit %>% 
    group_by(Id, newgrp = str_c('Text_from_', 
        replace(Text_from, Text_from != "Customer", "Agent"))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = newgrp, values_from = value) %>%
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    summarise(AgentName = first(Text_from),
              Text_from_Agent = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Agent), collapse=' '),
              Text_from_Customer = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Customer), collapse = ' '))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     Id AgentName Text_from_Agent                                                                   Text_from_Customer                                
#  <int> <chr>     <chr>                                                                             <chr>                                             
#1    12 John      "Hi, How may I help you today? Please hold on for a moment. Yes, may I know whic… "Hi, I have a question regarding a car model Pric…
#2    13 Mike      Hi, How may I help you today? The price of this is $$$$$. Have a good day!        "Hi, I would like to know the price of ABC car mo…
```

---

Or using `spread`

```
 df2 %>%
    mutate(Body_text = sub("^.*Agent\\s\\w+", "", Body_text)) %>%
    separate_rows(Body_text, sep="\\s(?=\\w+:)") %>% 
    separate(Body_text, into = c("Text_from", "value"), sep=":\\s?") %>%
    na.omit %>% 
    group_by(Id, newgrp = str_c('Text_from_', 
        replace(Text_from, Text_from != "Customer", "Agent"))) %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(newgrp, value) %>%
    group_by(Id) %>% 
    summarise(AgentName = first(Text_from),
              Text_from_Agent = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Agent), collapse=' '),
              Text_from_Customer = str_c(na.omit(Text_from_Customer), collapse = ' '))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#     Id AgentName Text_from_Agent                                                               Text_from_Customer                             
#  <int> <chr>     <chr>                                                                         <chr>                                          
#1    12 Customer  "Hi, How may I help you today? Please hold on for a moment. Yes, may I know … "Hi, I have a question regarding a car model P…
#2    13 Customer  Hi, How may I help you today? The price of this is $$$$$. Have a good day!    "Hi, I would like to know
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column_id = 123, Column_text = "A: Hello B: Hi, How are you? A: I am good. What about you? B: Good, thanks"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))



df2 <- structure(list(Id = 12:13, Body_text = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Chat started: Thursday, December 5, 2019, 13:15:09\nChat Origin sales department\nAgent John\nJohn: Hi, How may I help you today?\nJohn: Please hold on for a moment.\nCustomer: Hi, I have a question regarding a car model Price.\n, John: Yes, may I know which model it is?\nCustomer: Yes, model abc.\nJohn:The price of this is $$$$$.\nCustomer: Thank you\nJohn:Have a good day.\n", 
"Chat started: wednesday, December 4, 2019, 13:15:09\nChat Origin sales department\nAgent Mike\nMike: Hi, How may I help you today?\nCustomer: Hi, I would like to know the price of ABC car model\nMike:The price of this is $$$$$.\nCustomer: Thank you\nMike:Have a good day!\nCustomer:Thanks, you too!\n"
), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```